# Como retornar valor ( Webhook )

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando usar o api.ai

https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook

Pelo que eu entendi, eu tenho que retornar um JSON no formato:

```
"fulfillment": {
     "speech": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F",
     "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample",
     "displayText": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F"
}
```

Mas como eu posso enviar essa mensagem pelo Webhook?